# python-sip: How to access a DLL from both Python and C++

Tags: c++, python, python-sip

I have a C++ GUI, it load a DLL when running. I use SIP to import the DLL in python. I need to embed the python part in the GUI, and some data are needed to exchange between python and C++.

For example, in the C++ GUI, I can enter command from a panel, such as "drawSomething()", it will call corresponding function in python, and the result will be shown in the GUI.

Can I use SIP to 
extract a C++ object from python object (just like the way boost.python does), or is there a better way to share data between python and c++ seamlessly?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I do not need to do anything complicated...
In my case, there is no difference to call functions in DLL from C++ or from python code embedded in C++.
I am totally over-thinked.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at this Library

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html

Comment: Is SWIG relevant if they're using SIP?

Comment: Thx for replying. I think SWIG is similar to SIP when extending python with C++ (dll --> pyd), and I am not sure whether SWIG or SIG has the ability to get data ***from python to C++***, when the module of python part is generated by one of them. I read the SWIG tutorial written by Beazley yesterday, and it seems for SWIG (probably the same for SIP), all the features are for C++ --> python. When C++ functions can run under python environment, that's the end of its job. Maybe my real question is only about Python Embedding